# Can't connect to parse AWS server except from host machine

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, parse-platform

I've set up an ec2 instance in aws with a parse server on it. I'm using it for an android app and it works just fine from the emulator on my host machine, except that it doesn't from any other machine/device - be it another emulator from another pc, doesn't matter if its on the same network or not, or an android phone.

I tried setting up another parse server in back4app and it works just as expected there, however that is not that much of a good solution since the free plan reaches its limit in the middle of the workflow of my app and that's not sufficient even for the presentation that I have to make.
As for the aws - I opened all traffic for all ports both on the inbound and outbound tabs from the security group - still nothing.
I tried accessing the dashboard via browser from another device and that works just fine but whenever I try to login from the app, it just times out - no response. Logs don't show anything, except for the fact that I have received the timeout toast. I tried connecting both to the dns and the public ipv4

```
Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .applicationId("{{appId}}")
                .clientKey("{{masterKey}}")
                .server("http://{{addr}}:80/parse/")
                .build()
        );
```

I'm pretty certain that its something to do with aws's security policy that I have missed to configure, since I'm not changing anything major when I try to connect to the back4app and the aws. Fact is - they both work from the emu, but aws doesn't from the phone.

Comment: Make sure you have seted app access key and secret key on your machine in root or initialize context with access key and secert key of user who has role define for ec2. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html to configure.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, definitely gave me a direction. I'll look into it as soon as I'm free but from first glance, seems like I need to make a new config class in the android project and I'll need to throw aws's sdk in there too... just found something called Amazon Cognito which seems to be the thing I might need.

Comment: I don't know if it has anything to do with your problem but you may not need the client key, and if you do you may be passing the wrong value.  It is optional on Parse Server, so if you haven't defined it there, just don't set it.  If you have, based on your code it looks like you're passing the master key which 1) is not the same thing and 2) should never be included in client code since that is the keys to the kingdom and anyone who gets their hands on it can do whatever they want to your parse installation.

Comment: Good to know, thank you for the info. I tried removing the client key and it indeed ran successfuly. My problem still persisted though :D Guess I'll never find a solution to that. Pretty much over with that project, it served its purpose with the free plan that I was using and it won't be going on prod or anything .. :)